# Themed based usercontrol asp.net

Tags: user-controls, app-themes

Is there any way to use a specific usercontrols depending on which theme the site is using?

Scenario:
I am using themes in my asp.net project. I am going to have same codebase and different look and feel and so using themes & skins.
Now the problem is if I want to have different headers & footers (which are usercontrols) depending on the type of site, how can we do with the help of themes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, control hierarchies can be modified with themes.

This is made possible by **ITemplate** properties that are **Themeable**.

If, for instance, you had a custom control that simply has a themeable **Contents** property you could say:

```
<custom:MyThemeableControl runat="server">
    <Contents>
    ... any valid *.skin markup here
    </Contents>
</custom:MyThemeableControl>
```

Now you could swap out the controls inside Contents for different themes as follows - for *ThemeA* you would have the following skin:

```
<custom:MyThemeableControl runat="server">
    <Contents>
        <asp:Button runnat="server" />
    </Contents>
</custom:MyThemeableControl>
```

And for *ThemeB* you would have the following skin:

```
<custom:MyThemeableControl runat="server">
    <Contents>
        <asp:TextBox runnat="server" />
    </Contents>
</custom:MyThemeableControl>
```

Then this page would render a **Button** under *ThemeA* and a **TextBox** under *ThemeB*:

```
<@Page Theme="ThemeA">
<custom:MyThemeableControl runat="server" />

<@Page Theme="ThemeB">
<custom:MyThemeableControl runat="server" />
```